# Pause between sending keystrokes to DirectX Application

Tags: c#, directx, wait, sendkeys, keystroke

I'd like to send a sequence of keypresses (to make up a word) to the window of a DirectX application followed by a pause before sending the `ENTER` key.

I'm able to send individual keypresses with the [InputManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate) library, but I'm unsure of how to implement "waits" in between certain key sequences with this keyboard hook.

ie: Send the message "Hello", wait for 250ms followed by the `ENTER` key.

SendKeys and SendWait will not work for what I'm doing, as they will not send keystrokes to the DirectX application.

Here is some pseudo-code explaining what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
using InputManager;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class form1: Form
    {
        private void helloButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.H);
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.E);
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.L);
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.L);
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.O);
            // (Wait 250ms)
            Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Thread.Sleep(250);` not work?

Comment: I'm still quite new to C# as this is my first application. I was unaware of Thread.Sleep. Do I just write that "as-is" between my keystrokes? EDIT: Sorry, I'm on mobile right now, but I just looked up Thread.Sleep, I'll update my question if it doesn't work for me. If you'd like, you could write tthat comment as an answer so I can accept it if it works for my project. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You will need a using statement for the `System.Threading` namespace.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.Sleep(250);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx). This will pause the currently working thread for `x` amount of milliseconds.

Note that you will need to include `System.Threading` in your using statements.